# Numpy tobytes() with defined byteorder

Tags: python, numpy, binary, endianness

Is it possible to define byte order when converting a *numpy* array to binary string (with *tobytes()*)?

I would want to force little endianness, but I don't want byte-swapping if it is not necessary.

Comment: You could experiment with `astype`.  Set the desired endedness in the dtype.

Comment: It seems that generating `bytes` always involve a copying. In order not to involve another copying when byte-swapping, use `a[:,None].view('B')[:,::-1].tobytes()` to output opposite-endian (opposite to what's described in the `dtype`, which is by default little)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When interfacing with C code I use this pattern

```
numpy.ascontiguousarray(x, dtype='>i4')
```

That dtype string specifies the endianess and precise bit width.

You can check ndarray.flags to see if conversions are necessary.